# Reduction from vertex-coloring problem to edge-coloring problem

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, np-complete, reductions

A few days ago I had a test and could not pass it. This is a question I did not understand in the test.

> We will look at the Edge-Coloring problem, in which, as is well known, we get as input graph G = (V, E) and natural number k and ask "Is there a coloration in arcs of G which uses at most k colors?". Remember, while painting vertices to two neighboring vertices must not have the same color, painting arcs to two neighboring arcs (i.e., having a common vertex) must not be
> The same color. That is, the language is:

Edge-Coloring = {<G,k>|G can be arcuated by coloring using ≤ k colors}

> Determine which of the following statements is correct:
>
> 1. The language is in P. An algorithm can be constructed running at time O (| V | * | E |), by reduction to the vertex-Coloring problem and then verifying that each color is ≤ k.
> 2. The language is in NP (and it is also possible that it is NP-complete, but this is not due to the question data)
> 3. The language is NP-complete, which is why vertex-Coloring is NP-complete and also $Edge-coloring \leq _pvertex-coloring $ can be performed by converting each arc to a vertex.
> 4. The language is NP-complete but not in NP
> 5. None of the above claims are true.

I think 3 is true, because in my opinion a reduction is made from the vertex-coloring problem which is NPC, and also the edge-coloring problem should be in NPC.

But I can not rule out 4, 2 and 5.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/142541/755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. We don't know whether this is true.
2. This is true, a certificate is an edge coloring with at most $k$ colors.
3. This is true. Edge coloring is a well-known NP-hard problem (see [here](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0210055) for a reduction from 3-SAT) and hence there is Karp reduction from every problem in NP to it. In particular there must also be a reduction from vertex coloring (which is NP-hard) to edge coloring.
   The reduction from edge coloring to vertex coloring creates a vertex $v_e$ for every edge $e$ in $G$ and an edge $(v_e, v_f)$ for every pair of distinct edges $e$ and $f$ in $G$ that share an endpoint.
4. This statement is clearly false since all NP-complete languages are in NP by definition.
5. This is false since, e.g., 2 is true.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the test has only one correct answer, and the solution you offered me contains 2 correct answers, also 2 and 3 correct actually?

Comment: Edge coloring is NP-complete (and hence it is in NP). It can shown to be NP-complete by observing that it is in NP and that vertex coloring is NP-complete (using the fact that vertex coloring $\le_p$ edge coloring as I argue in my answer). Moreover, it is also true that edge coloring $\le_p$ vertex coloring. Probably answer number 3 should have been worded as follows "The language is NP-Complete **because** there is a Karp reduction from vertex coloring to edge coloring". This claim would be false since you need the reduction to be in the opposite direction.

Answer (score 1):

- For (3), you are correct, i.e., the problem is NP-complete. As a side note, you might also like to know that you can solve edge coloring by using vertex coloring algorithms by taking the [line graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_graph). Note that this in itself does not prove NP-completeness.
- For (2), you need to show that if you given a certificate, then you can verify it in polynomial time. In this case, the certificate is the coloring, i.e., a color per edge. Given that certificate, you can easily check in polynomial time whether the given coloring is a proper edge-coloring. I encourage you to check the details.
- For (4), you should check the definition of NP-completeness. If a problem is NP-complete, then by definition it is also in NP.
- Question (5) is now trivial.